# Implementation of `aes.h` functions in openssl

Tags: c, openssl

In openssl, where can i find the implementation of `AES_encrypt` which is a function in the header file `aes.h`.

Answer (score 1):

> ... where can i find the implementation of AES_encryption

Its `AES_encrypt`, not `AES_encryption`. You will find it in `aes_core.c`.

```
$ grep -IR AES_encrypt * | cut -f 1 -d ':' | sort | uniq | grep '\.c'
apps/speed.c
crypto/aes/aes_cbc.c
crypto/aes/aes_cfb.c
crypto/aes/aes_core.c
crypto/aes/aes_ctr.c
crypto/aes/aes_ecb.c
crypto/aes/aes_ige.c
crypto/aes/aes_ofb.c
crypto/aes/aes_wrap.c
crypto/aes/aes_x86core.c
crypto/evp/e_aes.c
crypto/modes/cts128.c
crypto/modes/gcm128.c
```

However, you should be using `EVP_*`, and not `AES_*` directly. `AES_*` is a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.